# How to escape '/' in connection string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection-string, amazon-athena, apache-superset

I have '/' in connection string and it might be treating as '/' while putting in connection string. I am connecting Athena with Apache Superset from superset.

According to official docs I am using pyathena:

https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/athena

```
awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}&...
```

I am trying to use the same configuration as given in official docs:

```
awsathena+rest://KDB45:199USqN/88C13Cw/VVCdGC0k@athena.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod-ak?s3_staging_dir=s3://abc/def
```

I am getting error:

```
An error occurred while creating databases: Connection failed, please check your connection settings
```

I have 'slashes' in my secret key. I think it might be the problem that is giving:

```
199USqN/88C13Cw/VVCdGC0k
```

I tried following to make it workable but it is not working:

```
awsathena+rest://KDB45:199USqN/\\88C13Cw/\\VVCdGC0k@athena.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod-ak?s3_staging_dir=s3://abc/def
```

Another method:

```
  awsathena+rest://KDB45:199USqN%2F/88C13Cw%2F/VVCdGC0k@athena.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod-ak?s3_staging_dir=s3://abc/def
```

I even tried urllib library of python to see if there is come decode to use.But there is no change for this `" 199USqN/88C13Cw/VVCdGC0k"`

```
urllib.quote("P@ssword")
```

I also tried replacing `s3://... -> s3%3A//..` but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `s3://... -> s3%3A//..` try changing `/` in the secret to `%2F`:

`199USqN/88C13Cw/VVCdGC0k` -> `199USqN%2F88C13Cw%2FVVCdGC0k`